2 step regressor
I plan to proceed with regression analysis in two steps. The first step involves predicting lifespan using a regression model. In the subsequent step, the lifespan predicted in the first step is used as an independent variable in another regression model. Is it appropriate to use predicted values as independent variables in another predictive model? What methods should be employed to verify the accuracy of the model, such as whether the variability of the model has been amplified?

Welcome to Cross Validated! It typically makes more sense to build a single comprehensive model rather than pursuing this 2-step approach, but it's hard to know in this case without more information about the nature of your study. Please edit the question to say more about the data you are analyzing and the hypothesis that you are testing. Note that comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted on this site, so please provide that extra information by editing the original question.

You may want to read up about regression applications such as error correction models, instrumental variables models, Cragg models, and similar 'two-stage' regressions.

Look up “generated regressors” as this is what you’re describing. Because the predicted value that’s used as an independent variable in the second stage has estimation error of its own, the standard errors on its coefficient coming out of the second stage regression will be too small unless adjusted.
